# How to turn Table auto-expand feature off?

Tags: excel, format, vba

I want to copy some ranges, in the `Helper` Worksheet.

Indeed I want reformat that copied ranges and set them into `Format as Table`.

Each ranges contains a Title wanted be non `Table format`.

I tried code below:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(UpLeft,1).Address ":" & Cells(DownRight, 20).Address), , xlYes).Name = "Table" & i
```

Everything is good when I perform first range to copy, but when I do copy next ranges, Previous 'Table format` have automatically expand and disturb Titles and Headers of the current range.

I had set end of each copied range size to entire print area Height using

```
(IIf(WS.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape, 591, 852) - WS.PageSetup.TopMargin - WS.PageSetup.BottomMargin) * _ (100 / WS.PageSetup.Zoom) - 1
```

And add end of each copied range a Page brake with

```
WS.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Rows(sh + 1).
```

And I need each range have start from top of page, so I cant leaving gaps between pastings

How can I prevent Table auto expand in a specific Worksheet?

Comment: Are you leaving sufficient gaps between the pastings? And are each paste a new object?

Comment: No. I had set end of each copied range size to entire print area `Height` using `(IIf(WS.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape, 591, 852) - WS.PageSetup.TopMargin - WS.PageSetup.BottomMargin) * _
        (100 / WS.PageSetup.Zoom) - 1` and add end of each copied range a Page brake (`WS.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Rows(sh + 1)`). And I need each range have start from top of page, so I cant leaving gaps between pastings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn autoexpand off:

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = False
```